# Listing numbers with non-repeating digits

Tags: list-manipulation, digits

I tried to search this but could not find. Given a number of digits(the maximum being 0 to 9), how can I generate a list of all possible numbers without repeating the digits in each number? e.g. Given the digits 1,2 & 3 I should get 123, 132, 213. 231, 312, & 321. I want to generate such a list of digits with all digits from 0 to 9.
Thanks. I am relatively new at Mathematica and am trying to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lists of digits of the numbers you are looking for are mere permutations of the digits $0,\,1,\,2\,\dotsc,9$. `Permutations` can provide you with these permutations; `FromDigits` turns them into numbers.

```
FromDigits /@ Permutations[Range[0,9]]
```

This simply ignores leading 0-digits.
If you want only numbers with 10 true digits, you can use the following:

```
FromDigits /@ Drop[Permutations[Range[0, 9]], 9!]
```

Comment: 0 can't be the first digit.

Comment: Leading `0` digits are removed automatically.

Comment: Or this `Drop[FromDigits /@ Permutations[Range[0, 3]], 9!]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Very good point. It's much faster. Thanks.